# Array to mvc controller with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get some data (multidimensional array) to my GET controller (for display in a modal/dialog box) from a list (the user checks some values and then gets sent to a modal/dialog box that should display the chosen values):

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var prop= [];
        prop['Name'] = "TEST";
        prop['Id'] = "123"
        data.push(prop);
    }
});
```

When I log this (above) data, it looks fine. Then I use it the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ data }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

I've a Model for using the data in the action (and the partial view):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is my action:

```
    public ActionResult Merge(MyClass[] theData)
    {
       ...
    }
```

But in the action the 'theData' is always null. If I use 'POST' in the ajax, the POST action gets called, and I don't want to do that in this step. I want to use the POST action after, when the user have made some modifications (eg. Title change) and then saves. THEN I do a POST and saves the new data.

Comment: `MyClass[] theData` is not a multi-dimensional array. And it needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ theData: data }),`

Comment: So I cannot use MyClass[] theData, or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes of course you can - just use `data: JSON.stringify({ theData: data }),` - my comment is that `MyClass[]` is an array (not a multi-dimensional array)

Comment: Oops - just noticed that its a GET so that will not work. You need to make it a `type: "Post",` otherwise you will need to prefix each property with the relevant indexers

Comment: Yeah. That's the problem I guess? Kinda new to MVC, but as I understand it I cannot have two POST actions in my controller? Correct me if I'm wrong. I need the second one (POST) for the second action if u understand what I mean.

Comment: You don't need to change the controller - just `type: "Post",` and `data: JSON.stringify({ theData: data }),` in the ajax

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, I've two actions in my controller (one get, and one post). So I get "ambiguous" error when I change it to POST in the ajax call. The first one is just to display the selected data in a modal (partial view) and the second is to apply these changes from the partial view.

Comment: Then create another method to POST to or build you own url to the GET method which needs to be `.../Merge?[0].Name=someValue&[0].Id=someValue&[1].Name=someValue&Id=....` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116102/discussion-between-rangerover-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in your `Merge()` method is `MyClass[] theData` which means you need to send an array of objects, not an array of arrays. Start by changing the script to generate the data to

```
var data = [];
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        data.push({ Name: 'TEST', Id: '123' });
    }
});
```

Next, you need to change the method to a `[HttpPost]` (rename it if necessary to avoid any conflict with any existing `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Merge( .. )` method).

Then you need to change the type to `"Post"` and stringify the data with the name of the methods parameter before sending it

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post', // change this
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ theData: data }), // change this
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function () {
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

Side note: If you did want to do this to a `[HttpGet]` method, then it would be be necessary to send the data as `.../Merge?[0].Name=TEST&[0].Id=123&[1].Name=TEST&[1].Id=123` etc (i.e. with indexers), however you should not generally be sending collections of objects to a GET method. Apart from the ugly query string, you could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
  $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var prop= {};
            prop.Name  = "TEST";
            prop.Id = "123"
            data.push(prop);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your data as a string. Don't use JSON.stringify

Change
`data: JSON.stringify({ data })`
to
`data: data`